# How to multi JOIN in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a query in SQL Server as:

```
SELECT MD.Author_ID, MD.CoAuthor_ID, MD.Venue_ID, A2P.pid [Paper_ID], 
       P.abstract_research_area_category_id [Paper_Category_ID], 
       MD.Year
FROM Merged_Data MD
JOIN sub_aminer_author2paper A2P ON MD.Author_ID = A2P.aid AND
                                    MD.Year      = A2P.p_year AND
                                    MD.Venue_ID  = A2P.p_venue_vid
JOIN sub_aminer_paper P          ON MD.Venue_ID  = P.p_venue_vid AND
                                    MD.Year      = P.p_year
WHERE MD.Author_ID = 677
```

Whereas I'm unable to get desired results because unable to join `A2P.pid` with `sub_aminer_paper` for extracting `[Paper_Category_ID]`.

*How can I join `A2P.pid` with `sub_aminer_paper` to have a `pid` match and extract `[Paper_Category_ID]` whereas `sub_aminer_paper` has the field `pid`?*

Comment: Can you explain the problem with this query? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: @Mureinik No, I just want to join `pid` from `sub_aminer_paper` with `A2P.pid` which I have already selected by joining from `sub_aminer_author2paper` to extract `Paper_Category_ID` because it only exists in `sub_aminer_paper`

Comment: Can you add the `A2P.pid = p.pid` in the WHERE clause, it causing any issue?

Comment: @Arulkumar Oh yes, it worked! ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589595/how-to-multi-join-in-sql-server#comment60777357_36589595) it solved the issue. So the same, I provide the answer for the question:

```
SELECT MD.Author_ID, MD.CoAuthor_ID, MD.Venue_ID, A2P.pid [Paper_ID], 
       P.abstract_research_area_category_id [Paper_Category_ID], 
       MD.Year
FROM Merged_Data MD
JOIN sub_aminer_author2paper A2P ON MD.Author_ID = A2P.aid AND
                                    MD.Year      = A2P.p_year AND
                                    MD.Venue_ID  = A2P.p_venue_vid
JOIN sub_aminer_paper P          ON MD.Venue_ID  = P.p_venue_vid AND
                                    MD.Year      = P.p_year
WHERE MD.Author_ID = 677 AND A2P.pid = P.pid
```

Adding the `A2P.pid = P.pid` in the WHERE clause will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
    SELECT MD.Author_ID, MD.CoAuthor_ID, MD.Venue_ID, A2P.pid [Paper_ID], 
           P.abstract_research_area_category_id [Paper_Category_ID], 
           MD.Year
    FROM Merged_Data MD
    INNER JOIN sub_aminer_author2paper A2P 
    ON (MD.Author_ID = A2P.aid AND
        MD.Year      = A2P.p_year AND
        MD.Venue_ID  = A2P.p_venue_vid)
    INNER JOIN sub_aminer_paper P          
    ON (A2P.pid      = P.pid
        MD.Venue_ID  = P.p_venue_vid AND
        MD.Year      = P.p_year)
    WHERE MD.Author_ID = 677
```